# Best practice to create SparkSession object in Scala to use both in unittest and spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-submit

I have tried to write a transform method from DataFrame to DataFrame.
And I also want to test it by scalatest.

As you know, in Spark 2.x with Scala API, you can create SparkSession object as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.bulider
     .config("spark.master", "local[2]")
     .getOrCreate()
```

This code works fine with unit tests.
But, when I run this code with spark-submit, the cluster options did not work.
For example,

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --num-executors 10 ...
```

does not create any executors.

I have found that the spark-submit arguments are applied when I remove `config("master", "local[2]")` part of the above code.
But, without master setting the unit test code did not work.

I tried to split spark (SparkSession) object generation part to test and main.
But there is so many code blocks needs spark, for example `import spark.implicit,_` and `spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)`.

Is there any best practice to write a code to create spark object both to test and to run spark-submit?

Comment: Why can't you use `.config("master", "yarn-client")` in scala?

Comment: @cricket_007 Because I want to run test in local mode (in my laptop) and run the code in various environment which can be specified by spark-submit options.

Comment: I don't understand the issue, then. Of course you need to write import statements again in your unit test code.

Answer (score 6):

One way is to create a trait which provides the SparkContext/SparkSession, and use that in your test cases, like so:

```
trait SparkTestContext {
  private val master = "local[*]"
  private val appName = "testing"
  System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "c:\\winutils\\")
  private val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster(master)
    .setAppName(appName)
    .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "false")
    .set("spark.ui.enabled", "false")

  val ss: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
  val sc: SparkContext = ss.sparkContext
  val sqlContext: SQLContext = ss.sqlContext
}
```

And your test class header then looks like this for example:

`class TestWithSparkTest extends BaseSpec with SparkTestContext with Matchers{`

Answer (score 2):

I made a version where Spark will close correctly after tests.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, FunSuite, Matchers}

trait SparkTest extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfterAll with Matchers {
  var ss: SparkSession = _
  var sc: SparkContext = _
  var sqlContext: SQLContext = _

  override def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    val master = "local[*]"
    val appName = "MyApp"
    val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster(master)
      .setAppName(appName)
      .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "false")
      .set("spark.ui.enabled", "false")

    ss = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate()

    sc = ss.sparkContext
    sqlContext = ss.sqlContext
    super.beforeAll()
  }

  override def afterAll(): Unit = {
    sc.stop()
    super.afterAll()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The spark-submit command with parameter --master yarn  is setting yarn master.
And this will be conflict with your code master("x"), even using like master("yarn").

If you want to use import sparkSession.implicits._ like toDF ,toDS or other func,
you can just use a local sparkSession variable created like below:

val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("YourName").getOrCreate()

without setting master("x") in spark-submit --master yarn, not in local machine.

I advice : do not use global sparkSession in your code. That may cause some errors or exceptions.

hope this helps you.
good luck!

Answer (score 0):

How about defining an object in which a method creates a singleton instance of SparkSession, like `MySparkSession.get()`, and pass it as a paramter in each of your unit tests.

In your main method, you can create a separate SparkSession instance, which can have different configurations.

Comment: Could you please share a sample example of the same